# Will QGIS 2.0 work on Mac 10.8.5

Tags: qgis-2

I've downloaded QGIS 2.0 and have opened a project. All the layers are there, but it will not show the selections on the map. The attribute table shows the selected items. Am I missing something or is there some other cause?

Comment: Yes use http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis

Comment: That's where I got the complete download set. FreeType 4.10-1; GDAL 1.10; Geos Frame 4.2-2; matplotlib 1.3.0-3 and QGIS 2.0.1-7-Lion and Rgeos-0.2.5-1